# In-App Purchase in sandbox works occasionally

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, in-app

When I test the In-App purchase process, I get mixed results.

Sometimes The purchase is successful. sometimes it fails.

Is this behaviour normal for sandbox environment, or should I be worried?

Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close as too broad

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there might be some problem, may below link will help you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

This one includes code for displaying a store.

For more details please go through [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW5)

Comment: @TomerRubin always welcome :-)